# Meaning of Isaiah 65:16

Tags: isaiah, layers-of-meaning

What does “because he who is blessed in the earth will be blessed by the God of truth” mean?

> Because he who is blessed in the earth Will be blessed by the God of truth; And he who swears in the earth Will swear by the God of truth; Because the former troubles are forgotten, And because they are hidden from My sight!
>   ‭‭Isaiah‬ ‭65:16‬ ‭NASB‬‬

Answer (score 0):

**What does the expression “the former troubles are forgotten” mean Isaiah 65:16**

God continues on his promise to restore the repentant remnant of Israelites from their exile in Babylon. Isaiah writes:

Isaiah 65:15-16  (NASB)

> 15 “You will leave your name for a curse to My chosen ones,  And the
> Lord [a]God will slay you. But [b]My servants will be called by
> another name.  16 “Because he who is blessed in the earth  Will be
> blessed by the God of truth;  And he who swears in the earth Will
> swear by the God of truth; Because the former troubles are forgotten,
> And because they are hidden from My sight!

What does “because he who is blessed in the earth will be blessed by the God of truth” mean?

God by means of his prophet Isaiah addresses the Israelites who have forsaken him and are in captivity in Babylon:

Those truly seeking God will no seek a blessing from a false god or an idol, but from the "God of Truth". By swearing to the God of truth, the inhabitants of the land will have a reason for complete confidence in God, for he will have proved himself to be true to his promises. Safe in their homeland, the Jews will soon forget the former troubles.

Answer (score 0):

NASB 1995

> "Because he who is blessed in the earth Will be blessed by the **God of truth**;

by the God
בֵּאלֹהֵ֣י (bê·lō·hê)
Preposition-b | Noun - masculine plural construct
Strong's 430: gods -- the supreme God, magistrates, a superlative

of truth.
אָמֵ֑ן (’ā·mên)
Noun - masculine singular
Strong's 543: Sure, faithfulness, truly

The phrase "God of truth" comes from the Hebrew words Elohim and Amen, literally the God of the Amen.

2 Corinthians 1:20 refers to a similar idea:

> For no matter how many promises God has made, they are "Yes" in Christ. And so through him the "Amen" is spoken by us to the glory of God.

There is only one true God, the God of Amen. All blessings come from him who grants us the blessings.

Answer (score 0):

The RSV translation is "he who blesses himself shall bless himself by the God of truth".
The point  being, I suggest, that he shall use that name in such requests for blessing instead of an idolatrous name like Baal or Molech.
That then connforms with the following statement, that he who swears to the truth of something will use God's name instead of another name.
The logical connection with the final statement is that this fidelity to God is a symptom of, or the effect of, the fact that their "former troubles" (that is, their sin and disobedience) have been forgotten and forgiven by God and the old relationship is restored.